# Play jQuery animations in slow motion for debugging

Tags: jquery

When you have a page with complex animations with multiple divs and some abstractions on top of it (like knockout.js), it is sometimes hard to see why some elements are jumping around while animating.

One way to debug would be looking up for all the places where the animations are set, and multiply the animation lengths. This can be of course pretty tedious.

**Question**

Is there some nice dirty hack to show all jQuery animations of the current page in slow motion?

Comment: i guess you could extend animate method and multiply speed parameter passed to it and don't forget to reinitialize jQuery.fx.speeds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extend animate method, e.g:

(but duration can be passed as property of options object too, you will have to handle this case too!)

```
;(function($) {
    var slowingCoeff = 10;
    $.fx.speeds = {
        slow: slowingCoeff * 600,
        fast: slowingCoeff * 200,
        _default: slowingCoeff * 400
    };
    var oAnimate = $.fn.animate;
    $.fn.animate = function(prop, speed, easing, callback) {        
        if(typeof speed === "number")
            speed *= slowingCoeff;
        return oAnimate.call(this, prop, speed, easing, callback);
    }    

})(jQuery);
```

[basic DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/EQ32j/)

Comment: Sorry, it took a while before I had time to try this out. But brilliant! :) Thanks a lot!